# accessing redis connection from another python process

Tags: python, redis

How can I access a redis connection from another python process? Currently I am initializing the connection as:

```
import redis

pool = redis.ConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
r = redis.Redis(connection_pool=pool)
```

I want to access `r` from another process. At the moment I just re-initialize the connection from inside the other process which seems to work fine. Data that one one process pushes to the db are exposed to the other one, event notifications work fine too.

Is this the recommended way? Is there another way to do it without having to re-initialize the connection?

Comment: there is no problem to do multiple action on the same connection, Redis can handle this I just want to know what do u mean by another process is it another script or just a function on your current script

Comment: Thanx! yes it is another script. Very similar to publisher/subscriber pattern. Publisher is on `publisher.py` and subscriber on `subscriber.py`. They run on different python processes but they create the same `redis` connection. The subscriber listens to whatever the publisher publishes, seems to work ok